# Is it possible to use fullcalender slotEventOverlap option in the timeline view?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is it is possible to use fullcalender slotEventOverlap option in a timeline view? I want to show the overlapping time.
I have used https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view

Comment: Please add what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted fullcalernder support team and the solution is

"The slotEventOverlap setting does not apply to the timeline view because it doesn't allow events to overlap.  You could make a custom timeline view if you need them to overlap."